# How can add filterExpressions NUSoap code with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, xsd, obiee

This is my sample code and works fine.I tried adding it in different places but failed.
I struggled for a long time and finally decided to write it here. Because I couldn't get out of it. My English is not enough. I'm sorry for this.

```
<?php

require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$oSoapClient = new nusoap_client('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/analytics/saw.dll?WSDL', 'wsdl');
if ($sError = $oSoapClient->getError()) {
    echo "The operation could not be performed [" . $sError . "]";
    die();
}
$logon = array('name' => 'xxxxxxxxx', 'password'=> 'xxxxxxxxx');
$sessionID = $oSoapClient->call("logon", $logon, "", "", "", "", "rpc", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", "encoded");    



$reportRef = array (        
    'reportPath' => '/shared/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'reportXml' => null
    );
$xmlOpts = array (
        'async' => 'false', 
        'maxRowsPerPage' => '100',
        'refresh' => 'true',
        'presentationInfo' => 'true'
        );


$param = array(
    'report' => $reportRef,
    'outputFormat' => 'SAWRowsetSchemaAndData',
    'executionOptions' => $xmlOpts,
    $sessionID
    );

$query = $oSoapClient->call("executeXMLQuery", $param, "", "", "", "", "rpc", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", "encoded");

print_r($query);

?>
```

How i can  add the code below filterExpressions please help !

```
<v6:filterExpressions>
<![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxxx"."xxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
</v6:filterExpressions><v6:filterExpressions>
<![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxx"."xxxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
</v6:filterExpressions><v6:filterExpressions>
<![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxx"."xxxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
</v6:filterExpressions>
```

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v6="urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v6:executeXMLQuery>
         <v6:report>
            <v6:reportPath>/shared/xxxxxxxxxx</v6:reportPath>
            <v6:reportXml>sonoras imperio</v6:reportXml>
         </v6:report>
         <v6:outputFormat>SAWRowsetSchemaAndData</v6:outputFormat>
         <v6:executionOptions>
            <v6:async>true</v6:async>
            <v6:maxRowsPerPage>9999</v6:maxRowsPerPage>
            <v6:refresh>true</v6:refresh>
            <v6:presentationInfo>false</v6:presentationInfo>
            <v6:type>per auras</v6:type>
         </v6:executionOptions>
         <v6:reportParams>
         <v6:filterExpressions>
<![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxx"."xxxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxxxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
</v6:filterExpressions><v6:filterExpressions>
<![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxx"."xxxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxxxxxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
</v6:filterExpressions><v6:filterExpressions>
<![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxxxxx"."xxxxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxxxxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
</v6:filterExpressions>
</v6:reportParams>
         <v6:sessionID>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</v6:sessionID>
      </v6:executeXMLQuery>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I send the following xml with soapUi 5.6 it works.How can i send this with nuSoap ?? Problem is i can't send the <v6:filterExpressions>

```
 $client = new SoapClient("https://xxxxxxxxxxx/analytics/saw.dll?WSDL", array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));
   /*$functions = $client->__getFunctions();
   foreach($functions as $func) {
      echo $func . "\n";
   }*/

   $logon = array('name' => 'xxxxxxx', 'password'=> 'xxxxxxxxxx');
   $SessionID = $client->logon($logon);

   $reportRef = array (     
    'reportPath' => '/shared/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'reportXml' => null
    );
$xmlOpts = array (
        'async' => 'false', 
        'maxRowsPerPage' => '100',
        'refresh' => 'true',
        'presentationInfo' => 'false'
        );

 $xmlstr = <<<XML
             <filterExpressions>
            <![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxxx"."xxxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxxxxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
            </filterExpressions>
            <filterExpressions>
            <![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxxxxxx"."xxxxxxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
            </filterExpressions>
            <filterExpressions>
            <![CDATA[<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal" xmlns:saw="com.siebel.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:sawx="com.siebel.analytics.web/expression/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:sqlExpression">"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"."xxxxxxxxxxxxx"</sawx:expr> <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:double">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>]]>
            </filterExpressions>       
XML;

$param = array(
    'report' => $reportRef,
    'outputFormat' => 'SAWRowsetSchemaAndData',
    'executionOptions' => $xmlOpts,  
    'reportParams' => $xmlstr,     
     'sessionID' => $SessionID->sessionID
    );



$query = $client->executeXMLQuery($param);

print_r($query);

} catch (Exception $exc) {
  echo "Soap Hatasi Olustu: " . $exc->getMessage();
}
```

I am tested this code is not correct. You have an idea ?? please help me. I can't send $xmlstr.